# Delphi IDE (Code Insight) extremely slow on a semi large project

Tags: delphi, ide

I've been working on a project that I update from time to since a few years through the various Delphi versions, currently on 10.3.1, and lately as I've been adding more features the editor is becoming progressively slower to the point I can barely type if Code Insight pops out, the editor keeps freezing for 1-3 seconds at a time, CTRL+Space takes also a while, compiling takes a few seconds until it actually starts, and clicking on "Save All" freezes everything as well for a few seconds.

I've read other questions about this issue and removed any unused units, as well as moving all I could after the implementation, but it has made no difference whatsoever.

Any tips? (already using IDE Fix pack, SSD, fast PC)

Comment: The new IDE (or its theming) are extremely slow for me too. You can of course switch off all the helpers, but it keeps being slower than, say, Tokyo or Berlin. Somehow, the IDE keeps refreshing itself for every little move. I **guess** you'll have to wait for the next major update.

Comment: I agree with Rudy. Unfortunately, the quality of the Rad Studio IDE has deteriorated rather severely recently. (I mean, now you cannot even maximize the IDE window (using Aero snap) without seeing major issues.)

Comment: Did you try updating to 10.3.2 ? I've heard people say it is better. Personally I've seen huge slowdowns in the IDE on big legacy projects which have tons of units in their uses clauses.

Comment: I's now 2023 and 11.4 is still extremely slow. It seems to get worse, not better with each update.

Comment: Performance for me in 11.3 is absolutely horrible. I CANNOT use Code Insight, but it's something I like, so I've suffered with the debilitating slowness for over a year. It takes 30+ seconds every time I edit something for the IDE to update the error list... Then I found this on Twitter https://twitter.com/cpp_delphi_dave/status/1605876180296548353 I put DelphiLSP.exe from Delphi 11.1 in the Delphi bin folder (replaced the existing one), and the performance issues are gone. Now when I edit code, it doesn't completely refresh the Code Insight cache. IT IS SO MUCH BETTER NOW! I like Delphi again

Comment: @MaxKielland - FYI, replace DelphiLSP.exe in the Delphi `bin` folder with the same EXE from Delphi 11.1, and your performance issues should be fixed.  It's disappointing that they've been "working on a fix" since Dec 2022 (Twitter post), and still haven't solved the issue -- especially when it worked so much better in version 11.1.